# How to merge 4 lists into 1 in python

Tags: python

my code is like

```
testGraph=open(input("Enter a file name:"))
for line in testGraph:
  temp=line.split()
```

and the out put is like

```
['0', '1']
['2', '1']
['0', '2']
['1', '3']
```

and I want to make them into

```
[['0', '1'],['2', '1'],['0', '2'],['1', '3']]
```

could someone help me?

Comment: so? Make a list to which you `append` each `temp`.

Comment: Are you trying to `split` at whitespace or at each character?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.chain()` to flat lists into one list.

```
>>> cmd = ['ls', '/tmp']
>>> numbers = range(3)
>>> itertools.chain(cmd, numbers, ['foo', 'bar'])
<itertools.chain object at 0x0000000003943F28>
>>> list(itertools.chain(cmd, numbers, ['foo', 'bar']))
['ls', '/tmp', 0, 1, 2, 'foo', 'bar']
```

But if you want to have a list of lists, then appending to the list would be your choice.

```
testGraph=open(input("Enter a file name:"))
result = []
for line in testGraph:
  result.append(line.split())
```

Comment: Who asked about flattening lists?

Comment: From the title of the question, that's what I thought the author asked for.  I added the other option as well (having lists of lists, and not merge 4 lists into 1)

Answer (score 2):

`List comprehension`, works for you,

```
testGraph = open(input("Enter a file name:")) 
result = [line.split() for line in testGraph]
```

**Execution:**

```
In [29]: testGraph = open('abc.txt')

In [30]: [line.split() for line in testGraph]
Out[30]: [['0', '1'], ['2', '1'], ['0', '2'], ['1', '3']]
```

Comment: When you iterate over the lines of a file each line has a trailing newline, so in your example, `testGraph.split('\n')` is actually different to how a file would behave. You need to also do `line.strip()`

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen But it's just an example, In file it doesn't require any `strip`, split will remove work perfectly, That's the first code sample shows.

Comment: Oh gosh, my bad. I forgot how split() worked. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

This should work with minimal change to your code. `temp` will then have the combined list you want.

```
testGraph=open(input("Enter a file name:"))
temp = []
for line in testGraph:
  temp.append(line.split())
```